# On the question of lp compactness. Counterxamples

Tags: compactness

Is it a unity norm, closed sphere, in lp, (not Lp ), compact ? I hear that it is not !! Is there a counterexample for this or a proof ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

Spheres in an infinite-dimensional Banach space are never compact.

In this case it's easy to find a sequence of points in the sphere with distance $\ge 1$ between them.